# Analyze Frequency of Data Access in Table

Tags: sql

There is a table in which complete data is stored. There is a created date column in the table. The table is in use in a live application. 
Is there any way to define a date range (based on the created date column in the table) for the data access trend?
Like the previous 3 months data is getting accessed (selected) very frequently, older than that is accessed rarely, older than 2 years is never accessed.

Comment: Tag appropriate database name with sample data and your expected output.

Comment: Depending on a query sql engine may choose to access, search the entire table even when a final result set contains only a couple of rows.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some [sample data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)